# State Not getting Updated In NextJs Latest Version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
"use client";
import { useState , useEffect } from "react";

import React from 'react'

function page() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [disable,setDisable] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(username.length>0 && email.length>0){
       setDisable(false);
    }else{
       setDisable(true)
    }
  },[username,email])

  const handleSubmit = () =>{
     
  }
   
  return (
    
    <>
    <label htmlFor="name" >Name</label>
    <hr />
    <input type="text" name="name" value = {username} className="text-black" 
     onChange={(e)=>{
        setUsername(e.target.value);
     }}
    /> <hr />
        <label htmlFor="email" >Email</label> <hr />
    <input type="text" name="email" value = {email}  className="text-black" 
     onChange={(e)=>{
        setEmail( e.target.value)
     }}
    /> <hr />
    <button onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={disable}>Submit</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default page
```

The state is not getting updated in the latest next version , can someone tell me what I am missing??

This is the app/page.tsx and as it is using useState , I updated it this way , please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

a few things should be changed in your code:

- components name should always be in uppercase, so it should `Page` not `page`
- you don't need to use `useEffect` here, since `username` and `email` are state values you can create a new `const disableSubmit = !username.length || !email.length;`. `disableSubmit` value will change when `username` or `email` values change

check this codesandbox example

[image: Edit brave-chandrasekhar-pgjh3s]